# Ranking across rows

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
      Date       AAPL      NFLX       INTC    AAPL_Ret   NFLX_Ret   INTC_Ret
0 2008-01-31  27.834286  3.764286  25.350000       
1 2008-02-29  27.847143  3.724286  24.670000   -0.07     0.25       -0.05     
2 2008-03-31  25.721428  3.515714  22.670000    0.15     0.10       0.06  
3 2008-04-30  25.377142  3.554286  22.879999    etc
4 2008-05-31  24.464285  3.328571  22.260000
```

I want to calculate quantiles for the stock returns going across the rows in my df. So for example, the quantiles (let's say we use 3 groups) would rank the first row of returns as AAPL and INTC in quantile 3, and NFLX in quantile 1 (since it's the highest return). The expected output would be (below, scroll to right):

```
      Date       AAPL       NFLX       INTC    AAPL_Ret   NFLX_Ret   INTC_Ret   AAPL_Ret Q   NFLX_Ret Q   INTC Ret Q
0 2008-01-31  27.834286  3.764286  25.350000       
1 2008-02-29  27.847143  3.724286  24.670000   -0.07     0.25       -0.05        3              1            3
2 2008-03-31  25.721428  3.515714  22.670000    0.15     0.10       0.06         1              2            2
3 2008-04-30  25.377142  3.554286  22.879999    etc
4 2008-05-31  24.464285  3.328571  22.260000
```

What I've tried: I originally wanted to use pd.qcut with something like axis=1 in the formula but the method doesn't take an argument like that. So I thought I could do something like a for loop (since I will eventually expand the file to many stocks)

```
for col in df.columns:
    if '_Ret' in col:
        df[col+'_Rank'] = df.apply(pd.qcut(df[col], 5, labels=np.arange(5, 0, -1), axis=1)
```

But I'm stuck here.

Would greatly appreciate your help, am a python beginner. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way could be to use `filter` to select only columns with '_Ret' and `stack` to make it as a serie to be able to use `qcut` after.

```
# I only copy the two rows with values in _Ret columns
print (df.filter(like = '_Ret').stack())

1  AAPL_Ret   -0.07
   NFLX_Ret    0.25
   INTC_Ret   -0.05
2  AAPL_Ret    0.15
   NFLX_Ret    0.10
   INTC_Ret    0.06
```

Now you can use `qcut` on this serie and followed by a `unstack` and `add_suffix` to rename:

```
df_Q = (pd.qcut(df.filter(like = '_Ret').stack(), 3, labels=np.arange(3, 0, -1))
           .unstack().add_suffix(' Q'))

print (df_Q)
  AAPL_Ret Q NFLX_Ret Q INTC_Ret Q
1          3          1          3
2          1          2          2
```

Just need to `join` with the original dataframe as the row's numbers are the same than in the original one.

```
df = df.join(df_Q)
```

giving the expected output

Comment: Thank you so much Ben, fantastic and elegant answer, does exactly what is needed.